# Could you help how to use If Else if under Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check till the last row of Column Z and replace the cells with comment "NOT SET" where the Cell Value is '0'. My range starts from Z2. Below is my code:

```
sub notset() 
dim ws as worksheet  
set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("master sheet")
with ws
.range("Z2:Z" & range("Z" & row.count).end(xlup).row).formula =_
"=if((Z2 = '0'),"NOT SET"")"
end sub
```

Comment: You cannot do that with a formula that will refer to itself.  Use `Range.Replace`

Comment: Set the number format on the Z column to `0;0;"NOT SET"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula that refers to itself will not work.  Just use `Range.Replace`

```
Sub notset()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("master sheet")
    With ws
        .Range("Z2:Z" & Range("Z" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Replace "0", "NOT SET", xlWhole
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks. Could u tell if I want the value in some other column say "AA" then how can I use the If /else if with formula function? what changes need to make here .range("Z2:Z" & range("AA" & row.count).end(xlup).row).formula =_
"=if((Z2 = '0'),"NOT SET"")"